# How to create daily expense from a start-date end-date data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do data processing on a sales and expense data set. The data has start-date and end-date (non-uniform duration). I need to convert the expense data into daily data for all days between and including start-date and end-date.

I am using Python 3.6 and trying to working with Pandas. I tried to use the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Work\Samsung\ZZ.Codes for Automating\Data.xlsx')
df.mydates = pd.date_range(df['Start Date'], df['End Date']).tolist()
print(df)
```

I know the approach is not correct compared to the output I need, but I wanted to see the output is stored in another column in the data-frame. But I am getting the error anyway.

My input looks like below:

```
   Category Brand Subbrand Start Date   End Date      Sales   Expense
0       C01   B01      S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19   29445891  10943244
1       C01   B01      S02 2017-01-01 2017-01-27  190582635   9614901
2       C01   B01      S03 2016-02-03 2016-03-04   78779415   9450124
3       C01   B02      S01 2016-01-01 2016-12-31   55267620  11460273
4       C01   B02      S02 2016-12-25 2017-03-06  120107421   8406527
5       C01   B02      S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31   90111536   7775826
6       C01   B03      S01 2017-01-01 2017-01-27   32969210   6915853
7       C01   B03      S02 2016-02-03 2016-03-04  128042469   8548281
8       C01   B03      S03 2016-01-01 2016-12-31  169384918  11810253
9       C02   B01      S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19   47879682  10355269
10      C02   B01      S02 2018-12-20 2018-12-31   78764777   9814553
11      C02   B01      S03 2017-01-01 2017-01-27  109319359   6156288
12      C02   B02      S01 2016-01-01 2016-12-31  109478365   5111520
13      C02   B02      S02 2016-06-16 2016-08-19  112928078  10275697
14      C02   B02      S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31   80626697   9078153
15      C02   B03      S01 2016-02-03 2016-03-04   36118823   6066609
16      C02   B03      S02 2016-12-25 2017-03-06  156779337   8715303
17      C02   B03      S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31   55672206   5914943
```

My Expected output:

```
Category Brand Subbrand Start Date End Date Sales Expense Duration Daily_Date Daily Expense
C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19 29445891 10943244 65 2016-06-16 168357.6
C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19 29445891 10943244 65 2016-06-17 168357.6
C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19 29445891 10943244 65 2016-06-18 168357.6
C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19 29445891 10943244 65 2016-06-19 168357.6
…. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. ….
C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19 29445891 10943244 65 2016-08-17 168357.6
C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19 29445891 10943244 65 2016-08-18 168357.6
C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16 2016-08-19 29445891 10943244 65 2016-08-19 168357.6
C01 B01 S02 2017-01-01 2017-01-27 190582635 9614901 27 2017-01-01 356107.4444
C01 B01 S02 2017-01-01 2017-01-27 190582635 9614901 27 2017-01-02 356107.4444
C01 B01 S02 2017-01-01 2017-01-27 190582635 9614901 27 2017-01-03 356107.4444
…. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. ….
C01 B01 S02 2017-01-01 2017-01-27 190582635 9614901 27 2017-01-26 356107.4444
C01 B01 S02 2017-01-01 2017-01-27 190582635 9614901 27 2017-01-27 356107.4444
…. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. ….
C02 B02 S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31 80626697 9078153 12 2018-12-20 756512.75
C02 B02 S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31 80626697 9078153 12 2018-12-21 756512.75
C02 B02 S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31 80626697 9078153 12 2018-12-22 756512.75
…. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. …. ….
C02 B02 S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31 80626697 9078153 12 2018-12-30 756512.75
C02 B02 S03 2018-12-20 2018-12-31 80626697 9078153 12 2018-12-31 756512.75
```

Please show me a direction toward solving this problem.

Thank you :).

Comment: Can you please format your output correctly and confirm your column names are accurate? It's somewhat confusing what your desired is currently

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The Column name explanation is as below:
**Daily Date** = Dates that fall in the bracket of start date and end date
**Duration** = no. of days within the start date and end date bracket. The formula is End date - start date + 1
** Daily Expense** = the expense of each entry split to daily expense by dividing the Expense column with the duration

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that multi-day expenses are uniformly spread across the days that they span?

Comment: Yes.. that is the assumption we are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see your expected answer as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Work\Samsung\ZZ.Codes for Automating\Data.xlsx',sheet_name=0,parse_date=["Start Date","End Date"])
df['Daily'] = df['Expense']/(((df['End Date']-df['Start Date']).dt.days)+1)

zipped = zip(df['Category'], df['Brand'], 
             df['Subbrand'], df['Start Date'], df['End Date'], df['Sales'],df['Expense'], df['Daily'])

L = [(C, B, S, SD, ED, Snum, Enum, x, Dnum) for C, B, S, SD, ED, Snum, Enum, Dnum in zipped for x in pd.date_range(SD, ED)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Category', 'Brand','Subbrand','Start Date','End Date','Sales','Expense','Daily_date','Daily'])
```

I have directly Calculated daily value but if you want Difference of day then you can also keep it separate in while zipping the data.

Output will be as below:

```
    Category    Brand   Subbrand    Start Date  End Date    Sales   Expense Daily_date  Daily
0   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-16  168357.600000
1   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-17  168357.600000
2   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-18  168357.600000
3   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-19  168357.600000
4   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-20  168357.600000
5   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-21  168357.600000
6   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-22  168357.600000
7   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-23  168357.600000
8   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-24  168357.600000
9   C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-25  168357.600000
10  C01 B01 S01 2016-06-16  2016-08-19  29445891    10943244    2016-06-26  168357.600000
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1648    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-21  492911.916667
1649    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-22  492911.916667
1650    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-23  492911.916667
1651    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-24  492911.916667
1652    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-25  492911.916667
1653    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-26  492911.916667
1654    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-27  492911.916667
1655    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-28  492911.916667
1656    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-29  492911.916667
1657    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-30  492911.916667
1658    C02 B03 S03 2018-12-20  2018-12-31  55672206    5914943 2018-12-31  492911.916667
```

Kindly have look from your-end and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This works like a charm... Thank you... Just one question, though.. is it possible to remove the hardcoding of columns in the last line of the code and rather include all the columns available in the dataset? I am asking this because I will have data from multiple sources with inconsistent column names and number of columns.

Comment: yes, you can exclude the unnecessary columns while zipping the Specific column data

Answer (score 1):

I have used only relevant columns and excluded columns like brand etc.

```
duration = abs(pd.to_datetime(data.start_date) - pd.to_datetime(data.end_date))
data['duration'] = duration.apply(lambda d: d.days + 1)
data['daily_expense'] = data.apply(lambda x: x['expense']/x['duration'], axis=1)

expanded_data = pd.DataFrame(data=None, 
                             columns=['start_date', 'end_date', 'expense', 'duration', 'daily_date', 'daily_expense'])

def expand_rows(sd, ed, exp, duration, daily_exp):
    global expanded_data
    single_row_expansion = []
    for d in pd.date_range(start=sd, end=ed):
        new_entry = {'start_date': sd, 'end_date': ed, 'expense': exp,
                     'duration': duration, 
                     'daily_date': pd.datetime.strftime(d.date(), '%Y-%m-%d'),
                    'daily_expense': daily_exp}
        single_row_expansion.append(new_entry)
    single_row_exp_df = pd.DataFrame(single_row_expansion)
    expanded_data = pd.concat([expanded_data, single_row_exp_df], sort=True)

data.apply(lambda r: expand_rows(*r), axis=1)
```

This will create a new dataframe with daily records.

Not sure what you want to do, but this is not an optimal way because you have lots of redundancy in the new dataframe. You can just create a duration column instead and calculate daily expense whenever needed. No need to expand the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `melt`

```
# duration
df['Duration']  = (df['End Date'] - df['Start Date']).dt.days + 1

# daily expense
df['Daily Expense'] = df['Expense']/df['Duration']

# date range to unfold
df['range'] = df.apply(lambda r: pd.date_range(r['Start Date'], r['End Date'], freq='D'),
                       axis=1)

# define the columns to melt
columns = df.columns[:-1]

# convert range to series
# merge with current df
# remove the old range
# melt and dropna
df['range'].apply(pd.Series) \
    .merge(df, right_index = True, left_index = True) \
    .drop(['range'], axis = 1)\
    .melt(id_vars = columns, value_name = "Daily_Date").dropna()
```